# Mysql ORDER BY numbers DESC

Tags: php, mysql, select, numbers, sql-order-by

I have a simple mysql select query in my PHP code:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT text FROM example ORDER BY rank DESC");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo $row['text'] . "<br>";
  }
```

and this MySql table:

```
   text | rank
--------+--------
 google | 245
--------+--------
 yahoo  | 32
--------+--------
 bing   | 12
```

When I get the results from the query, something like this gets displayed:

```
yahoo 
google
bing
```

I want Google to be in front. I guess Yahoo is in first because it starts with "3".

How could I make the query order the results by the size of the numbers in rank?

Thanks...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm guessing the `rank` field is some kind of string type. Make it a numeric type `int` and it will order properly

Comment: Thanks... I am so stupid. forgot to do that :P Will accept the answer :)

Comment: No problem. Not sure if you will have issues maintaining your `rank` data when switching the column type. If you only have those 3 records, won't be anything, but if you have a lot, you might want to backup the data, and if it gets screwed up, you can run a script, convert all the values, and reinsert them.

Answer (score 7):

The correct solution, of course, is to use the correct data type. As a workaround you could cast the data to number on the fly:

```
SELECT text FROM example ORDER BY rank + 0 DESC
```

or:

```
SELECT text FROM example ORDER BY cast(rank as unsigned) DESC
```

Answer (score 3):

What's the data type of `rank` in your SQL schema? Set it to a numeric type.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM example ORDER BY rank DESC");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
  echo $row['text'] . "  ". $row['rank'] ."<br>";
}
```

And see if the ranks are being sorted correctly.

Answer (score 1):

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `example` ORDER BY `rank` DESC");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
  echo $row['text'] ."<br>";
}
```